# C# error parsing to query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

> System.Data.SqlServerCeException (0x80004005): There was an error parsing to the query. [Token line number = 1, Token line offset = 120, Token in error = @price ]

I keep getting this error when running my program and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've tried changing multiple things around and it keeps giving the same error, just the number after "Token line offset = " changes sometimes.

```
static public void Insert(string _id, string _city, string _state, string _country, int _beds, int _baths, int _price)
{
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCeCommand commandInsert = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO [House] (id, city, state, country, beds, baths, price) VALUES (@id, @city, @state, @country, @beds, @baths, @price", connection);
            commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", _id);
            commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", _city);
            commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", _state);
            commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", _country);
            commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@beds", _beds);
            commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@baths", _baths);
            commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", _price);
            commandInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlCeException exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
}
```

Code within buttonclick

```
private void btn_insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (txt_id.Text != "" && txt_city.Text != "" && txt_state.Text != "" && txt_country.Text != "")
        {
            SQLFunctions.Insert(txt_id.Text, txt_city.Text, txt_state.Text, txt_country.Text, int.Parse(txt_beds.Text), int.Parse(txt_baths.Text), int.Parse(txt_Price.Text));
            SQLFunctions.Refresh(this.dataGridView1);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forget to close your `VALUES(` part with `)` after your `@price` parameter.

```
VALUES (@id, @city, @state, @country, @beds, @baths, @price)
```

A few things more;

- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling close method manually.
- Do not use `AddWithValue` method as much as possible. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specif your parameter type and it's size.

Comment: I was using `Add` initially but then it kept underlining my code in green and said it was obsolete or something and to use `AddWithValue` and it went away.

Comment: @Alex Only `Add(String, Object)` overload is obsolete. You can use [`Add(String, SqlDbType, Int32)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ay66z617%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
query="INSERT INTO [House] (id, city, state, country, beds, baths, price) VALUES ('@id', '@city', '@state', '@country', '@beds', '@baths', '@price')";
```

and replace your `try` with this

```
 connection.Open();
            SqlCeCommand commandInsert = new SqlCeCommand(query, connection);
            commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", _id);
            commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("city", _city);
            commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("state", _state);
            commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("country", _country);
            commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("beds", _beds);
            commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("baths", _baths);
            commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("price", _price);
            commandInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```